@peculiar/webcrypto - can not access to crypto.subtle
I am using @peculiar/webcrypto 1.5.0.(node v18.18.2)
To test my logic, I need crypto.subtle.
Below is simple test code in my jest.setup.js.
const { Crypto } = require('@peculiar/webcrypto');
global.crypto = new Crypto();
console.log('>>>', global.crypto.subtle);

I know, peculiar has subtle module in its ts, however when I print crypto.subtle, it shows undefined. Is there anything I missing?
How can I retrieve subtle?
===== Updated 07/09
It is not a problem of peculiar. The basic problem is Can not update global.crypto. I will update if I found anything ..

It seems not reasonable to me. But below code is working
// jest.setup.js

// This works well
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('util');
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;

// global.crypto = new Crypto() will not update global variable
const { Crypto } = require('@peculiar/webcrypto');
const peculiarCrypto = new Crypto();
delete global['crypto']; // Remove global since it is not modifiable
global.crypto = peculiarCrypto;

maybe global.crypto is immutable and global.TextEncoder is mutable.
